# How to restart a web server created by fastapi?

Tags: pyside6

I create a web server with fastapi , code example like this :

```
import sys 
import os 
import threading 
import pynput from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
 
 
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        
        start_button = QPushButton('Start Web Service', self)
        start_button.clicked.connect(self.start_web_service)
        layout.addWidget(start_button)

        
        stop_button = QPushButton('Stop Web Service', self)
        stop_button.clicked.connect(self.stop_web_service)
        layout.addWidget(stop_button)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

    def start_web_service(self):
        
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=os.system, args=('uvicorn easydemo:app --reload --log-level=info',))
        self.thread.start()

    def stop_web_service(self):
        
        

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        with pynput.keyboard.Controller() as controller:
            controller.press(pynput.keyboard.Key.ctrl)
            controller.press('c')
            controller.release('c')
            controller.release(pynput.keyboard.Key.ctrl)
        event.accept()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MyWidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

After produce a exe file with pyinstaller,
Open the file , Click "Start Web Service",it will start easydemo web server in a cmd command window.

Now , If i want to  restart the web server  , How should i do ?

Comment: You should certainly not use `os.system()` for that, and doing it in a thread is for the wrong reason. At least use subprocess, that provide proper access to the launched process, or eventually consider QProcess. Also note that if those lines in `closeEvent()` are intended to close the prompt, they're both pointless and wrong: when that handler is called, the current window is probably active, so those events will probably never be sent appropriately, but, most importantly, even assuming that it would have worked, you're making a *terrible* assumption about the window that would receive them.

Comment: @musicamante  Can you show me some code ?  this code is created by chat··gpt...  i really a newbee for python...

Comment: Sorry but no, as that's not the purpose of StackOverflow, especially if you're trying to learn coding from a generative AI as ChatGPT is (which are completely *unreliable* for learning and programming in general, except for experienced programmers). I strongly suggest to learn in the proper way, by following tutorials, patiently studying the documentation, and walking all the proper steps in the correct order.